# How to change octal string to char?

Tags: python, python-3.x, char, octal

So i'm trying to login web-client wifi login page with python. The web-client keep generating special octal character for every login session. So what i'm trying to do is:

requests.get(web-client).text -> get the octal code by looping the text index -> combine with the password

the problem is:

-if i write

```
password="password"
special="\340" + password + "\043\242\062\374\062\365\062\266\201\323\145\251\200\303\025\315"
print(special)
```

it returns =

```
àpassword#¢2ü2õ2¶Óe©ÃÍ #this is what i want, python translate it to char
```

-but if i index the webpage

```
import requests
webtext= requests.get(web-client url).text
password= "password"
special1= ""
special2= ""
for i in range(3163, 3167): #range of the first octal
    special1 = special1+webtext[i]
for i in range(3204, 3268): #range of the second octal
    special2 = special2+webtext[i]
special=special1+password+special2
print(special)
```

it returns =

```
\340password\043\242\062\374\062\365\062\266\201\323\145\251\200\303\025\315
```

as you can see it's not decoded to char, the python translate it as a string. So what should i do to get the same result?

btw i'm simulating the requests by opening the saved text file of the web-page html

Comment: octs are outh of range for the normal character type.

Comment: \340 wont fit into the -127 to 128 range, so you need to try converting all this to unicode

Comment: try `special = unicode(special, "utf-8")`

Comment: what module should i import to use 'unicode'? i did `import unicode` but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
my_string = "\\043\\242\\062\\374\\062\\365\\062\\266\\201\\323\\145\\251\\200\\303\\025\\315"
bytes(my_string, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
```

Comment: it returns `Ã` not `à`, they are different aren't they?

Comment: `bytes("\\340", "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")` gives `'à'`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
>>> def convert_oct_to_string( oct ) :
...     return ''.join([chr(int(i,8)) for i in oct.split('\\') if len(i) > 1])
... 
>>> convert_oct_to_string( "\\340" )
'\xe0'
>>> convert_oct_to_string( "\\043\\242\\062\\374\\062\\365\\062\\266\\201\\323\\145\\251\\200\\303\\025\\315" )
'#\xa22\xfc2\xf52\xb6\x81\xd3e\xa9\x80\xc3\x15\xcd'
>>>
```

---

This should answer some questions below

```
Python 2.7
>>> "\340"
'\xe0'

Python 3.4
>>> "\340"
'à'
```

Just in case, same stuff in Python3:

```
>>> def convert_oct_to_string( oct ) :
...     return ''.join([chr(int(i,8)) for i in oct.split('\\') if len(i) > 1])
... 
>>> convert_oct_to_string( "\\043\\242\\062\\374\\062\\365\\062\\266\\201\\323\\145\\251\\200\\303\\025\\315" )
'#¢2ü2õ2¶\x81Óe©\x80Ã\x15Í'
```

Comment: what im trying to do is to get the char from the oct

Comment: @RamadhanFajarIhsan exactly what I did.

Comment: if i do `>>> "\340"` it returns `à`

Comment: @RamadhanFajarIhsan Nope, see above.

Comment: `if len(i)` could be replaced by `if i`.

Comment: it should returns `à` not `'\xe0'`

Comment: @RamadhanFajarIhsan in python3 it returns "a", in python2 what I use, it returns "\x0e" which is exactly the same. try my code in your version of python and see if you get what you want.